# iOS Custom Input View located at an arbitrary location on the screen?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to define a custom view for an input field (like a UITextfield or something similar), but have that view automatically shown in a place other than the bottom of the screen? Is it possible to have it only take up part of the width? For example, can it slide in from the top-left part of the screen and only be 300px wide?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible.  Why don't you just set the frame size to be 300px wide and set the origin to be off screen.  Then move it into a viewable portion of it's super frame with animations.

Comment: I want my input view to be handled correctly by all UIResponder objects. I've already got a solution where I have to show and hide the thing by myself, but I want to create an integrated solution.